# Can a pipeline works for more than one class?

Tags: python, class, for-loop, scikit-learn, pipeline

my dataset consist of 10 feature (10 columns) for input and the last 3 columns for 3 different output. If I use one column for output, for example y = newDf.iloc[:, 10].values , it works; but if I use all 3 columns it gives me an error at pipe_lr.fit and says: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (852, 3) instead.
How can I pass y ?

```
X = newDf.iloc[:, 0:10].values
y = newDf.iloc[:, 10:13].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

pipe_lr = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                    PCA(n_components=2),
                    LogisticRegression(random_state=1, solver='lbfgs'))

pipe_lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Please always provide the full error traceback.  Here, the traceback identifies which step of the pipeline is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The `pipeline` itself does not care about the format for `y`, it just hands it over to each step.  In your case, it's the `LogisticRegression`, which indeed is not set up for multi-label classification.  You can manage it using the [`MultiOutputClassification` wrapper](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html#sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier):

```py
pipe_lr = make_pipeline(
    StandardScaler(),
    PCA(n_components=2),
    MultiOutputClassifier(LogisticRegression(random_state=1, solver='lbfgs'))
)
```

(There is also a `MultiOutputRegressor`, and more-complicated things like `ClassifierChain` and `RegressorChain`.  See the [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#).  However, there is not to my knowledge a builtin way to mix and match regression and classification tasks.)

Answer (score -1):

Simply put, No.
What you want is called multi-label learning, not supported by Scikit-Learn.

You should train three models, each having a label.